# Displaying a messaging right away to the user when page is loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am not sure if this is possible but I want to display a flash message to the user when they come onto on of the pages automatically. I kind of played around with it but no luck. Does anyone know how to do that if so any help would be greatly appreciated!

CODE FOR CONTROLLER

```
class BookinController < ApplicationController 
def flash
flash.now[:notice] = "Test"
render :action => :new
end
def bookin 
@alert = "Successfully saved!"
end 



def bookout

@customer_list = Customer.all 
@customer_name = params[:customer_name_in] 
@r = Customer.find_by_last(@customer_name) 

end

end
```

CODE FOR VIEW

```
<h2>The Maintenance Functions are restricted to authorized users.  
Please login below</h2>



  <%= form_tag(bookin_bookout_path, :method => "post") do %>

  <div class="field">

         Name

         <%= text_field_tag :customer_name_in %>
  </div>

  <br>

  Password  
         <%= text_field_tag :customer_name_in %>
  </div>


<br>
      <div class="actions">
      <br>

          <%= submit_tag "Submit Customer Name" %>

  </div>

   <% end %>

 <h2> <a href="http://localhost:3000/foodin/foodout">Main Menu</a></td> </h2>
```

Comment: This view belongs to which action

Answer (score 0):

You could try the bootbox-rails gem.

In a nutshell:

Add it to your Gemfile,

Add it to your app/assets/javascripts/applications.js

Put something like this in your view:

```
  <script>
      <%= raw @alerts %>
  </script>
```

Put something like this in your controller:

```
 @alerts = "bootbox.alert('Some kind of alert!');"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Flash**

You'll want to set the [flash message](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash) in the action, so it's there when the user hits the page

The flash is basically a `session variable` which will only persist per one action, meaning if you set it on your action, the next one will not have the same message

You can set the flash, as you've already done, like this:

```
def action
   flash[:notice] = "Welcome to our website"
end
```

---

**Code**

As `RSB` has queried, you've not provided us with the most specific code. So instead, I'll show you a simple example and look out for some comments to come back with updates:

```
#app/controllers/bookin_controller.rb
class BookinController < ApplicationController
   def index
      flash[:notice] = "Welcome To Our Page!"
   end
end

#app/views/bookin/index.html.erb
<%= flash[:notice] %>
```

This will display your message for the *rendered action*. You don't need any specific methods - just set the `flash` var value in the action you're rendering